# ARM Linux executable mysteriously runs on x86_64

Tags: c, linux, arm, cross-compiling

I'm using the Docker container (`thewtex/cross-compiler-linux-armv7`) to cross-compile a simple "Hello World" Linux user space C program on an `x86_64` system. The target system is a ARMv7 embedded system (in particular a Kobo Aura HD e-reader with stock firmware).

The source code of the program (`hello_world.c`) is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Unexpectedly, I can execute the resulting executable on the host system:

```
andreas@andreas-pc:~/tmp/test$ uname -a && ./hello 
Linux andreas-pc 4.5.5-201.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat May 21 15:29:49 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Hello World!
```

as well as on the target device

```
[root@(none) onboard]# uname -a && ./hello 
Linux (none) 2.6.35.3-850-gbc67621+ #1038 PREEMPT Thu Apr 25 15:48:22 CST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
Hello World!
```

Is there any explanation for this?

---

For reference, I invoke the compiler using the following set of commands

```sh
docker run thewtex/cross-compiler-linux-armv7 > ./dockcross.sh
chmod +x dockcross.sh
```

For some reason the generated shell script is buggy, I manually have to replace `/cross-compiler-base/cross-compiler-linux-armv7/` and `/:build/:build:z/` in `dockcross.sh`. Now I run

```sh
./dockcross.sh arm-linux-gnueabihf-cc hello_world.c -static -o hello
```

`file` returns the following information about the resulting `hello` executable

```sh
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=317a9ea164931f614b24e98dec743050e2d7f900, not stripped
```

Comment: Possibly someone configured [binfmt_misc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) for you and set it so that arm executables run qemu.

Comment: Thanks, binfmt_misc is indeed the mechanism that allows this magic. I'll post an answer to this question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a mechanism in the Linux kernel called [binfmt_misc](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt?id=HEAD) that can be used to associate arbitrary interpreters with executables. This association can either be based on a magic byte sequence at the beginning of the executable itself, or its file extension (e.g., `wine` automatically registers itself for `*.exe` files). Interpreters are registered in the kernel by writing to the `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` sysfs.

On Fedora, the `systemd-binfmt` service is responsible for the interpreter registration. It reads a set of configuration files from the `/usr/lib/binfmt.d` directory and performs the necessary writes to the sysfs. In the context of the above question, installation of the `qemu` emulator-suite will place the corresponding configuration files in this directory. For ARM this file is called `qemu-arm` and has the following content:

```
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm
flags: 
offset 0
magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002002800
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

This allows to transparently execute statically linked ARM executables on Linux. Thanks to Mark Plotnick for pointing this mechanism out.