# Running ARM binaries on x86_64

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, x86-64

I'm not sure if SO is the best place to ask this question but...

I've compiled my C program on, Linux Ubuntu (16.04), using

```
gcc -o MM1.x86 -O3 -static -mavx2 -g -Wall MM1.c
```

Running the file command

```
file MM1.x86 

MM1.x86: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=078be440b466ba97bd4bf468b24eee35f8c6a01f, not stripped
```

But I've also cross compiled the same source file for ARM using

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o MM1.ARM -O3 -static -g -Wall MM1.c
```

Running file

```
file MM1.ARM

MM1.ARM: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=b6582e1073682d41eb5262ad5393cebb8578e05d, not stripped
```

But after running the ARM compiled program, I was wondering how does it even run on x86_64 if it was compiled for ARM architecture?

```
lscpu

Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz  
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               886.640
CPU max MHz:           4000.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              7183.90
Virtualisation:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

I did notice that the ARM version runs slightly slower, why is this so?

Comment: Probably related : [ARM Linux executable mysteriously runs on x86_64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912290/arm-linux-executable-mysteriously-runs-on-x86-64)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARM Linux executable mysteriously runs on x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912290/arm-linux-executable-mysteriously-runs-on-x86-64)